# ReferenceError: sdkbox is not defined cocos2d-js

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have been unable to integrate the SDKBOX successfully. I am on windows and using Cocos Code IDE. I used the guide at http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/facebook/v3-js/ and followed all steps but I am unable to configure the SDKBOX into my project.As when I even try to initiate sdkbox using "sdkbox.PluginFacebook.init();" , I get ReferenceError: sdkbox is not defined. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add more context to the question, add the smallest amount of code required to reproduce the issue and people will be more likely to help/able to help

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix the problem .  I have the same issue,  I just integrate SDKBOX to my cocos2d-js project, but it complains sdkbox not defined.

Comment: @BjörnKaiser the problem has no relation with the code. The SDKBOX is just not integrating. And thus, I cant use it.

Comment: @Emmy, I have not been able to fix the problem so far. I have actually given up now.

Comment: @WajahatAliKhan   sdkbox only support native platform not the browser apps.   but I could not make sdkbox plugin work on native either.  I tried to use IAP plugin, but I could never make it work.

Comment: @Emmy Yes! I know that there is no support for web platform. It should work for Android and iOS though, **but it doesn't**.

Answer (score 0):

You do not register the `sdkbox` module, you should use this:

```
sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_PluginFacebookJS);
sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_PluginFacebookJS_helper);
```

as can be seen [here](https://github.com/sdkbox/sdkbox-sample-facebook/blob/master/js/frameworks/runtime-src/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp#L80-L81)

And SDKBox provides an [example](https://github.com/sdkbox/sdkbox-sample-facebook).